Apple sign in doesn't ask for email
I tried to add Apple sign in to my mobile app, but every method doesn't work. It just creates blank account in firebase and doesn't return any email.
I tried:

Deleting my app from apps using Sign in with Apple in settings (haven't done anything, because the pop up even doesn't ask for email)

This code:
Future<User> signInWithApple({List<Scope> scopes = const [Scope.email, Scope.fullName]}) async {
    final result = await TheAppleSignIn.performRequests(
        [AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: scopes)]);
    switch (result.status) {
      case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        final AppleIdCredential = result.credential!;
        final oAuthCredential = OAuthProvider('apple.com');
        final credential = oAuthCredential.credential(
            idToken: String.fromCharCodes(AppleIdCredential.identityToken!));
        final UserCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final firebaseUser = UserCredential.user!;
        if (scopes.contains(Scope.fullName)) {
          final fullName = AppleIdCredential.fullName;
          if (fullName != null &&
              fullName.givenName != null &&
              fullName.familyName != null) {
            print(fullName);
            final displayName = '${fullName.givenName}${fullName.familyName}';
            await firebaseUser.updateDisplayName(displayName);
          }
        }
        print(firebaseUser.email);
        return firebaseUser;
      case AuthorizationStatus.error:
        throw PlatformException(
            code: 'ERROR_AUTHORIZATION_DENIED',
            message: result.error.toString());

      case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
        throw PlatformException(
            code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER', message: 'Sign in aborted by user');
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }


This code:
Future<void> signUpWithApple() async{
    final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
    appleProvider.addScope('email');
    var credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
    print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email);
    print(credential.user);
  }



This code aswell:
void appleSign() async {
    AuthorizationResult authorizationResult =
    await TheAppleSignIn.performRequests([
      const AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email, Scope.fullName])
    ]);

    switch (authorizationResult.status) {
      case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        print("authorized");
        try {
          AppleIdCredential? appleCredentials = authorizationResult.credential;
          OAuthProvider oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider("apple.com");
          OAuthCredential oAuthCredential = oAuthProvider.credential(
              idToken: String.fromCharCodes(appleCredentials!.identityToken!),
              accessToken:
              String.fromCharCodes(appleCredentials.authorizationCode!));
          print(appleCredentials.email);
          UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oAuthCredential);
          print(userCredential.user!.email);
        } catch (e) {
          print("apple auth failed $e");
        }

        break;
      case AuthorizationStatus.error:
        print("error" + authorizationResult.error.toString());
        break;
      case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
        print("cancelled");
        break;
      default:
        print("none of the above: default");
        break;
    }
  }

I've followed tutorial on YouTube (because I couldn't find docs for this packages) and created everything in apple developer account, Xcode etc the same way. I am 99% sure that scopes determine if I (as a developer) should have access to email if user agrees to that, but the popup doesn't contain the window to hide it or use it.
App is ready for android, the iOS version is missing only the apple sign in function. Please help me sleep at night.

Apple only provides the user's email on the first login, so if something goes wrong with the Firebase Authentication flow, you will have to save it somewhere (local storage preferably) and use the Firebase admin SDK to update the user's record later.
Also, delete the Firebase user using the Firebase console after deleting your app from apps using Sign in with Apple in the settings
Here's an example of how you can get the email when there is a FirebaseAuthException after a successful Apple Authorisation.
AuthorizationCredentialAppleID? appleCredential;
    try{
      
      appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
      );
      
      final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider('apple.com')
          .credential(idToken: appleCredential.identityToken);
      
      final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
      
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      final email = appleCredential?.email;

      if(email != null){

        final appleUserId = appleCredential!.userIdentifier;
        // Save the Apple user email and `userIdentifier` because the email 
        // will not be available on subsequent Apple authorisations
      }
    } on SignInWithAppleException catch (e){
      print(e);
      // Apple error 
    }



but the problem is, I don't EVER get email. The pop-up with the ability to hide it or use it never appears. I can just log in with password and that's all. It creates blank user in firebase

@Sohatzky Have you tried deleting the blank Firebase user from your dashboard after deleting your app from apps using Sign in with Apple in the settings?
It seems you're using the_apple_sign_in package, which hasn't been updated for three years. I highly recommend transitioning to the sign_in_with_apple package I used in my shared example.
Remember to delete the blank Firebase user from your Firebase dashboard.
